# asp.net with sql server tree view

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

There is a table of three tables join below,can anyone help me out?:

```
StoreID   StoreName  DepartmentID   DepartmentName  StoreID  EmployeenName DepartmentID

 1    FlagshipStore    1          FinancialDepartment  1        Mr1          1
 2    BranchOfficeOne  2             TechnicalSection  2        Mr2          2
 2    BranchOfficeOne  3               SalesDepartment 2        Mr5          3
 2    BranchOfficeOne  4                  Receptionist 2        Mr6          4
 3    BranchOfficeTwo  5      AdministrativeDepartment 3        Miss1        5
 3    BranchOfficeTwo  6                   ,BackOffice 3        Miss2        6
 2    BranchOfficeOne  2              TechnicalSection 2        Miss3        2
 2    BranchOfficeOne  3               SalesDepartment 2        Mr7          3
 1    FlagshipStore    1           FinancialDepartment 1        Mr9          1
```

I would like to implement some things like:

```
  FlagshipStore
     FinancialDepartment
        Mr1
        Mr9
  BranchOfficeOne
     TechnicalSection
        Mr2
        Miss3
```

the treeview look like this!
tks in advance!

Comment: The above data is stored something like Store(StoreID, StoreName) Department(StoreID, DepartmentID, DepartmentName) and Employee(EmployeeName, StoreID?, DepartmentID?)

Comment: The sql server is sql server2008

Comment: Store(StoreID, StoreName) Department(StoreID, DepartmentID, DepartmentName) and Employee(EmployeeID,EmployeeName, ,DepartmentID)